# Required Type - capture of?

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa, java-17

I am stuck on an issue that involves generics. I understand the problem, but I do not know how call methods for JpaRepository. For instance, when I call **existsById** and pass a *Long* number value, I get **capture of ?** is required.

Below lies a snippet of the code:

```
private JpaRepository<?, ?> getRepository(Object repository) {
    if (repository instanceof JpaRepository<?, ?> repo) {
        return repo;
    }
    return null;
}
```

The repository:

```
@Repository
public interface IStatusRepository extends JpaRepository<Status, Long> {
}
```

The issue come here, when I try to call most methods from **getRepository(...)**:

```
public void test(IStatusRepository statusRepository) {
    ...
    var data = getRepository(statusRepository).findById(1L);
    ...
}
```

The code above results in a compilation error. The **findById(1L);** now takes a ***"capture of ?"*** and passing a *long* does not satisfy the compiler.

How can I call ***findById*** with no compilation error?

Comment: What is the purpose use of `getRepository`?  Why does the caller need to go through this addtional level of abstraction instead of just using `IStatusRepository` directly?

Comment: @AndrewS, for reusability of the same calls on different tables. Imagine if you had CRUD operations that are the same on different services, but data lies in different tables. In these services, I decided to reuse with abstraction, because the behavior is the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Problem

Generic parameters don't exist at runtime.
At runtime, the type of `JpaRepository<Status, Long>` is simply `JpaRepository`.

When you check `if (repository instanceof JpaRepository<?, ?> repo)` the check that is actually made is if it's an instance of `JpaRepository`, and that's it.

So what it returns can be a `JpaRepository` with any type arguments, hence the [`?` wildcards to say that the type is unknown](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/wildcards.html). From a type perspective, it doesn't mean that the returned type has the same type arguments as `repository`.

#### Solution (?)

As for how to satisfy this... Do you actually need to call `getRepository`? This function seems very hacky, and in your example, is not even needed, as you can call `statusRepository.findById(1L)` directly.

**For the sake of providing a solution, I'll give you one, but I strongly suggest against doing this.**

You could get rid of the compilation error by using raw type of `JpaRepository` :

```
// DO NOT DO THIS
private JpaRepository getRepository(Object repository) {
    if (repository instanceof JpaRepository repo) {
        return repo;
    }
    return null;
}
```

This would get rid of the compilation error (you'll likely get a warning), but then you open the way of having runtime errors (`ClassCastException`s) because you can assign the result to any type (`JpaRepository<String, String> data = getRepository(statusRepository);` would compile for example), which is way more dangerous than compile errors. You basically remove type safety here.